# count amount of rows in per half year with different years

Tags: mysql, count

I want to count amount of ID's for each month for the last half year, here is my query:

```
SELECT count(`Id`) FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(Created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) UNION SELECT `count(`Id`) FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(Created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) UNION SELECT count(`Id`) FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(Created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) UNION SELECT count(`Id`) FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(Created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) UNION SELECT count(`Id`) FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(Created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 MONTH) UNION SELECT count(`Id`) FROM `items` WHERE MONTH(Created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 MONTH);`
```

*`Created` is the time stamp of the created row.*

My problem is getting the fourth, fifth and sixth months. Because they were created in 2013 (different year), my query can't get their result.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(created), count(*)
FROM `items`
WHERE Created >= LAST_DAY(current_date() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY MONTH(created)
```

Where `LAST_DAY(current_date() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` will return the first day of the month where to start the count, you might also want to group by month and year:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m'), count(*)
FROM `items`
WHERE Created >= LAST_DAY(current_date() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y-%m')
```